# Can execve() be called from JVM?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

Is there a straightforward mechanism in Java to issue a `exec*()` system call so that the JVM is replaced with the new process? Python, e.g. has `os.exec*`, but I have found no equivalent for JVM languages. I don't want a child process, like `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`. I actually need the process image replaced.

@Deviluc suggests a C/JNI hack here:
[Java Program terminates after JNI method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851048/java-program-terminates-after-jni-method-call)

But I'm really hoping there is a simpler way in pure Java. Are we out of luck?

Comment: JNA maybe. Nothing in Java proper.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Could you also describe what are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: There is no way to do this in pure Java. How would this work on Windows, for example? It is still possible to achieve this with JNI / JNA / JNR etc.

Comment: @Cratylus: I have a legacy system running hundreds of instances of this Java process which, in some cases, delegates to compiled C as subprocesses, but this keeps the original JVMs in memory until the subprocesses finish, which bloats the memory footprint. The calling Java code exits immediately upon return, so exec*() would be a much cleaner option.

Comment: @apangin: Windows is not a concern at all. Seems like JNI is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments my understanding is that you run X instances of a java process and each forks a child process.
When a process is forked the parent process can not exit. If it did you end with an orphan process and this is not what you want.
You don't really give details what does this sub process do and why it needs to be done in a forked C program but what I would suggest is the following:
Create a wrapper process that communicates with the X java process and gets the input and returns the output.
So instead of having X java process + X child processes you would have the X java process + 1 wrapper process that calls the executable with different parameters.